# "Fingerprint cannot be generated" -Gitlab on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ssh, gitlab

I'm trying to setup Gitlab server. It flashes an error "Fingerprint cannot be generated" while adding ssh keys. I googled for the solutions and found a few possible problems that could cause this problem.

First was to ensure proper access from SELinux. Since I don't have SElinux installed, it can't be a problem.

Second was to make sure that `ssh-keygen` is installed and the keys generated do not have a pass phrase associated to it. Checked it and no issues.

Third was to check that user `git` can access the `tmp` directory created by Gitlab. I checked that too.

[This is the link](https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/development/install-gitlab-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr) I followed to set gitlab.

Comment: The permissions of `/tmp` should be `1777`. All users can write there. Are you sure you have diagnosed your problem correctly? The `git` user needs access to a `tmp` directory inside the Gitlab source dir structure afaik & that may have to be adjusted, but not `/tmp` ?

Comment: @Zanna I didn't know that. Anyway, I just checked for `tmp` inside Gitlab, made it accessible and it's still the same. Any other possible reason?

Comment: I don't know, but what makes you think it's a perms issue? Could you [edit] your question with a link to the instructions you're following or add more detailed error messages?

Comment: @Zanna : Just changed the question. I'm not sure where to find the logs as I'm new to it.

Comment: +1 to your question & hope someone can answer it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the version of Gitlab installed from those instructions (version 6.9.2) is too old (current version is 8.14) - `ssh-keygen` was then outputting MD5 based Fingerprint hashes; the default is now SHA256.  The solution, as garnered from - [Fixing gitlab's "Fingerprint cannot be generated" error](https://www.elwinar.com/articles/fixing-gitlab-s-fingerprint-cannot-be-generated-error) - is as follows:

- Edit `<path-to-gitlab>/app/models/key.rb`
- Change this line

`cmd_output, cmd_status = popen(%W(ssh-keygen -lf #{file.path}), '/tmp')`

- With this one

`cmd_output, cmd_status = popen(%W(ssh-keygen -E md5 -lf #{file.path}), '/tmp')`

- Restart Gitlab